# Button image change on a timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In my project I have a page which contains 5 image buttons laying horizantally.
When the page loads image on the  Button1  should change(remaining 4 buttons remains same).
After 3 seconds Button1 comes back to its original image and  image on Button2 will change.
After 3 seconds Button2 comes back to its original image and  image on Button3 will change.
And so on..
But After the Button5 is done , It should come back to the Button1 image again.
This should go on in a continuous loop.
Here is my code.But its not working I don't know the reason why its not working.
any help will be appreciated.

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    BeginRotation();
});

function BeginRotation() {
    rotateButton(0);
}

function rotateButton(buttonIndex) {
  var previousIndex = (buttonIndex + 4) % 5;

  var previousCurrentClass = 'main-nav-button' + (previousIndex + 1) + '-on';
  var previousNewClass = 'main-nav-button' + (previousIndex + 1);
  var currentClass = 'main-nav-button' + (buttonIndex + 1);
  var newClass = 'main-nav-button' + (buttonIndex + 1) + '-on';

  // alert('Previous Current Class: ' + previousCurrentClass + '\nPrevious New Class: ' + previousNewClass + '\nCurrent Class: ' + currentClass + '\nNew Class: ' + newClass);

  $('.' + currentClass).removeClass(currentClass).addClass(newClass);
  $('.' + previousCurrentClass).removeClass(previousCurrentClass).addClass(previousNewClass);
  window.setTimeout(rotateButton((buttonIndex + 1) % 5), 3000);
}
```

Comment: What kind of `not working`? Are you getting any javascript errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that is incorrect for sure

```
window.setTimeout(rotateButton((buttonIndex + 1) % 5), 3000);
```

It should be

```
window.setTimeout("rotateButton(" + ((buttonIndex + 1) % 5) + ")", 3000);
```

Comment: Greaattttttttt!!! Its working exactly what I wanted. Thanks for the solution and God bless You.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this code, but something like this should work:

```
jQuery(function($){
    var $btns = $('a.btn');
    var index = 0;

    setInterval(function() {
        $btns.removeClass('rotateThis');
        $btns[index].addClass('rotateThis');
        index = (index + 1 >= $btns.size()) ? 0 : index + 1;
    }, 3000);
});
```

$('a.btn') being whatever selector works to grab your image buttons of course.